# Automatically refreshing page every 60 seconds using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a simple digital clock and I want the page to reload every 60 seconds.

So basically when the minutes on the clock change I want the page to refresh automatically.

Below is my JS Code:

```
var date = new Date();
var h = date.getHours();
var m = date.getMinutes();
var s = date.getSeconds();

if (s == 60){   //If the seconds equal to 60 then update the minutes accordingly
  m++; 
}

window.onload = function(){
  if (h >= 12) {
    if(m < 10){
      var timePM = ' PM';
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =   h + ':' + '0' + m + timePM;
    } else{
      var timePM = ' PM';
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =   h + ':' + m + timePM;
    }
  }
  else{
    if(m<10){
      var timeAM = ' AM';
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =   h + ':' + + '0' + m + timeAM;
    }else{
      var timeAM = ' AM';
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =   h + ':' + m + timeAM;
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried using the following meta tag. However that did not seem to work.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
```

Comment: `setTimeout( () => window.location.reload(), 60000)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout function call only once so use setInterval function

```
setInterval("location.reload(true);", 60000);
```

it will refresh your page after one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you're done...

```
setInterval(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to write a digital clock. Here is a good sample :

```
https://codepen.io/afarrar/pen/JRaEjP
```

And this line of code will refresh your content:

```
setTimeout("Your String", 60000);
```